# Check if memory is low

Tags: windows-phone

I have some heavy tasks in my app so I want to run them only when the phone is not busy or has much free memory. Therefore I want to know how to check if the phone memory is low

Comment: Have you considered implementing this as a [Background Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202941(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: Yes. But I want to try another approach :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a property [`ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.applicationcurrentmemoryusage(v=vs.105).aspx) in the [`DeviceStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus_properties(v=vs.105).aspx) class.  Combined with [`ApplicationMemoryUsageLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.applicationmemoryusagelimit(v=vs.105).aspx), this should be enough to tell when you're running low on memory.

Comment: That's what I want. Easy and simple.